# Haskell - How to get the system OS directory?

Tags: haskell

The `directory` library contains many helper methods for getting certain reserved directories. However, as of the latest version (1.2.3.1), there does not appear to be a function that can get the system OS directory; e.g., "C:\Windows". I'd expect this to be a function like `getSystemDirectory`, but I don't see any equivalent. At least on Windows, it is possible for a user to install the OS to a non-standard location, therefore, it's not safe to make any assumptions as to its location.

Is there another library that exposes a function like this?

Comment: What would that mean for non-Windows systems? I use Linux and if you asked about where my "system OS directory" was I wouldn't know how to answer. (Then again, I'm hardly an expert!)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not entirely sure, either. I've never tried to stray out of the user space in Linux. (Maybe that would be equivalent to `root`'s home directory?) [Edit:] Actually, I think `/boot` would be the equivalent. Basically, it would be where the kernel lives.

Comment: Since “OS directory” is a Windows-specific concept, look for libraries dedicated to Windows programming. You can't do anything useful with the “OS directory” that isn't very specific to the OS anyway. In Windows, I expect that you can get the information through an environment variable (a portable concept) or through a registry key (a Windows-specific concept).

Comment: Gilles, any suggestions as to a library? That's what I was searching for and could find nothing on. I'm specifically trying to _avoid_ entering it, for a tool that can automate certain kinds of file changes. I'd rather do it in a more correct manner (library-supported), rather than hack it in. Worst case, I suppose I can use a library that wraps kernel32.

Comment: The environment variable `SystemRoot` will contain something like `C:\Windows`. (Try navigating to `%SystemRoot%` in Explorer.)

Comment: @stormont: Instead of avoiding certain directories based on the OS, I would consider letting the user specify which directories they *do* want your tool to monitor, and stay out of everywhere else.

Comment: @Mauris, that's part of the plan. Part of the tool involves a system-wide scan. I was planning on using checks for special folders to filter out critical paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Win32` library contains this functionality.

```
import System.Win32.Info

-- Calls Win32's GetWindowsDirectory() function in kernel32.dll
-- Corresponds to: C:\Windows
getWindowsDirectory :: IO String

-- Calls Win32's GetSystemDirectory() function in kernel32.dll
-- Corresponds to: C:\Windows\system32   
getSystemDirectory :: IO String
```

Comment: Annoyingly, searching for these doesn't show up in Hoogle or Stackage (at the time I posted this question).

Comment: https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%2Bwin32+getSystemDirectory hoogle searches a rather small set of packages by default.  There used to be (are?) OS specific flags in Google.

Comment: Yeah, I was aware of that, but I did think that Stackage was more consistent. Eventually, I found what I needed by looking up the Win32 methods in MSDN and searching for similar names through Google. (Of course, trying "Windows directory" doesn't help the results much, but "Win32" is more effective.) The missing key for Hoogle was knowing to look for the Win32 library to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to find OS specific operations is to tell hoogle which operating system you're talking about. Hopefully it is obvious when one is looking for something OS specific.  In this case you get success with the straight-forward [`os:windows system directory`](http://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=os%3Awindows+system+directory&scope=set%3Astackage).